# JQuery scroll to top of Bootstrap Modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently using the bootstrap modal plugin to display long legal messages on a website I'm designing, but the problem is that if you open one modal after the other, the second one will already be scrolled to whatever position the first one was. So I'm looking for a way to scroll a div to the top with JS/JQuery. This is the code I'm using currently:

HTML:

```
<!--MODAL-->
<div id="modal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="modalTitle"></h3>
</div>
<div id="modal-content" class="modal-body">
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button id="modalPrint" class="btn btn-info hidden-phone" onClick=''>Print</button>
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function openModal(heading, url) {
    $.ajax({
    url: url,
    cache: false
    }).done(function( html ) {
    $("#modal-content").html(html);
    $("#modalTitle").html(heading);
    $('#modalPrint').attr('onClick', 'loadPrintDocument(printCookies, {attr : "href", url : '+ url +', showMessage: false, message: "Please wait while we create your document"})');
    $('#modal').modal('show');
    $("#modal-content").scrollTop(0);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I've tried scrolling to the top after the modal has been shown. Any ideas?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Okay I've answered my own question. For anyone else with this issue, simply add this function to your JS!

```
$('#modal').on('shown', function () {
    $("#modal-content").scrollTop(0);
});
```

I will leave this question up, as there isn't one similar (that I could find) and it may help someone

Comment: Doing it on `hide` instead of on `shown` might make for a smoother presentation

Comment: it is a class. `.modal-content`

Answer (score 78):

Now with bootstrap 3 the events has change an can be achieved like this (plus a smooth animation to the top)

```
$('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'slow');
});
```

Comment: Looks like I'll have to upgrade to the new bootstrap if you can do things like that!

Comment: In this case it would be better not to have an animation, so that the modal was already scrolled to the top as soon as it opened, since from the user's perspective, it's a completely new modal unrelated to the last one.

Comment: Also note (assuming the approved answer is correct), both the event name and the object to be scrolled have changed (the modal div itself vs the modal's content div).

Comment: For some reason this only works when referecing the modals ID, i.e. `#modal` and not the class, i.e. `.modal`

Answer (score 7):

On Bootstrap 4 (v4.0.0-alpha.6) the following worked well for me:

```
$('#Modal').show().scrollTop(0);
```

Please note as of **bootstrap-4.0.0-beta.1** and **Firefox 56.0.1** this does not seem to work correctly;

I checked IE11, MS Edge and Chrome and this works fine.

Answer (score 7):

In Bootstrap 4, the following works for me:

```
$('.modal-body').scrollTop(0);
```

You need to scrollTop on the modal-body because the parent elements (modal, modal-dialog, modal-content) are containers and do not scroll with the user.

However, if you prefer a less jerky movement, try the animation route:

```
$('.modal-body').animate({scrollTop: 0},400);
```

Comment: thank you for this elegant solution and explanation - i was struggling with the other answers, getting frustrated - this '.animated' upgrade worked as desired with Bootstrap v5.1.0 - thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Scroll up button has a class of: **.page-scroll**

[image]

2. Modal with a class of: **.modal**
3. JS to make scroll happen with the modal (JS could be simplified):

   ```
   $('body').on('click', '.page-scroll', function(event) {
       var $anchor = $(this);
       $('html, body, .modal').stop().animate({
           scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
       }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
       event.preventDefault();
   });
   ```

Answer (score 3):

There was change in boostrap where you need to use: on shown.bs.modal

Call a function when you show the modal window (I opted for this method)

```
<button onclick="showSMSSummary(); return false;" 
data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click To View Summary" 
class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">SMS Summary</button>

function showSMSSummary()
{
   $('#HelpScreenModalContent').modal('show');            
   $('#HelpScreenModal').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 'fast');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[ScrollTop bootbox modal on fadeIn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636095/scrolltop-bootbox-modal-on-fadein) The answer is in this issue.

When setting up bootbox dialog add `.off("shown.bs.modal");`this at the end.

`bootbox.dialog({ ... }).off("shown.bs.modal");`

It will scroll be at top when open dialog.