# ScrollTop bootbox modal on fadeIn

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, scroll, bootbox

I use bootbox.js to make modal but when the modal fadeIn and the content is too long, the scrollbar goes at the level of the bottom button.
I need the scrollbar stay on top when modal appear

[image]

Comment: Show your code for showing bootbox.

Comment: `var bootboxAffiche = function(p_titre, p_contenu){
 bootbox.dialog({
  title : p_titre,
  message : p_contenu,
  buttons:{
   success: {
    label : 'Fermer',
    className: "btn-primary"
   }
  }
 });
}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved adding `.off("shown.bs.modal");` after the bootbox.dialog.

```
bootbox.dialog({ ... }).off("shown.bs.modal");
```

Comment: Works great. Makes you wonder why this wasn't built into bootbox.

Comment: This is discussed in [issue #260](https://github.com/makeusabrew/bootbox/issues/260) and is caused by auto-focusing the primary button in the `shown` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scrollTop with jQuery in you callback.

```
 bootbox.alert("Hello world!", function() {
      $('body').scrollTop(0);
    });
```